# What File System for a slow drive?

Tags: filesystems

I was planning a fresh Linux install on an old computer with a not-so-powerful hard drive. I read that different file systems (due to different internal data structure and architecture) might perform differently. For example, Ext4 is a well known and stable file system which performs quite good pretty much always, but in some cases "competitors" like XFS might be better (with parallel I/O for example).

Given a normal scenario (programming environment), which one would you suggest, based on your experience? And why (this is actually the more interesting part)?

Answer (score 0):

ReiserFS always performed well back in the day, when all we had were slow drives.

I think ReiserFS has fallen out of favor, since Hans Reiser was convicted of murder, and it's not well-maintained, but it never had that many problems to begin with.

Comment: I read about that and that Reiser4 was on the go when it was basically shut down. Would you use it as of today, given the circumstances?

Comment: @SamuelePilleri - I don't know about Reiser4, but the original ReiserFS was pretty good. I used it for some years on about 4 machines with no bad experiences. I personally never got killed, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually im learning about how to program using python and usually making many shell scripts for many purposes for many scenarios. And I have installed a Debian based distro with zfs and it work as well. I have an IDE disk drive with 120GB and a CPU Pentium IV up to 2.4 Ghz and belive me, it works very fast.

I hope it will work for you.

Just try it and enjoy it.